# How to match height of floating sibling divs

Tags: html, css

I have the following situation: http://jsfiddle.net/F3SqM/2/

I have two columns, I only know of the height of columnB. Both columns are floating, and I want columnA to match columnB's height (hence be full height).

I've tried setting height:100% on columnA relative to its parent, but this only works if the parent has a specified height, as in not height:100%. Unfortunately, the height of the parent is dependent on columnB and column B's height cannot be static.

I've looked around and tried the potential solutions i've found but none of these work, as most scenarios i've found online deal with a container having a specified height. Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Personally I like the equal height columns from www.ejeliot.com

http://jsfiddle.net/spacebeers/s8uLG/3/

You set your container up with overflow set to hidden, then on each div add negative margin-bottom and equal positive padding-bottom.

```
#container { overflow: hidden; }
#container div { float: left; background: #ccc; width: 200px; margin-bottom: -2000px; padding-bottom: 2000px; }
#container .col2 { background: #eee; }

<div id="container">
   <div>
        <p>Content 1</p>
   </div>
   <div class="col2">
        <p>Content 2</p>
        <p>Content 2</p>
        <p>Content 2</p>
        <p>Content 2</p>
   </div>
</div>
```

Faux Columns is also good and probably easier to set up but if you're really dead against using an image this is a pretty good method.

Comment: thanks for the cool technique, I fleshed this concept out a bit more over here: http://jsfiddle.net/jplew/yPMVJ/

Answer (score 1):

Quickest fix would be to use display:table-cell instead of floating:

http://jsfiddle.net/F3SqM/1/

However, this will only work in IE8+...

Answer (score 0):

You could put column B inside column A, this would make column A wrap B and thus take the same height.

Answer (score 0):

you can give the required height to the parent element as in [this](http://jsfiddle.net/KPNkz/) example

Answer (score -1):

You can use javascript to change the height of any other object, but you can't use CSS alone.

You say the height of B is dynamic, but without your code it's a bit hard to see why it can be dynamic and how I could write the js code for you.

Comment: Yeah, i've beent trying to avoid using javascript, but it seems to be heading in that direction and I'm writing code for it now. The columnB's height is dynamic because it lists images of a portfolio (the left column is to add a description for the portfolio). With PHP the container and column set will repeat below for each portfolio, so each portfolio's height will be different than the next.