# extend the background of a div to fill the parent div's height

Tags: css, joomla, html

I have tried a dozen different solutions and nothing seems to work.

http://betelec.ergonomiq.net/societe/offres-d-emploi

On the page above, I want the teal background of the left sidenav to extend to the height of the white container around it.

The white container gets its height defined by the height of the largest child div (in this case, the mainbody).

I have tried setting the sidenav's div height to auto, but the div remains fixed height. If I set the div to a very large number like 10000px and have overflow hidden, nothing gets hidden.

I am completely at a loss.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set parent element to `position: relative;` and then the child element to `position: absolute; height: 100%;`

Live example.

http://jsfiddle.net/pQdAr/

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your left sidebar is positioned by `float:left`.

The following post may help you. [How to match height of floating sibling divs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8417840/how-to-match-height-of-floating-sibling-divs)