# How to add an SVG canvas next to a div with the same height without messing up the layout

Tags: javascript, html, css, layout, svg

I have a `div` with several `div`s inside. The number of internal `div`s can change so the height of the outer `div` is dynamic. Then I have another `div` on the right of the first whose height must always match, which I want to use as an SVG canvas. I've solved the height issue using `table-row` and `table-cell` in CSS. But when I try to add SVG to it using a library such as Raphael or D3 the layout completely breaks. I've tried several variations and fixes suggested online with no success: if the canvas `div` doesn't change size then the SVG doesn't fill it up properly. Please help. I struggle to understand HTML and CSS layout.

You can see the problem here: http://jsfiddle.net/ofuh701p/4/ by clicking on the button. The black should all turn into red, without any layout changes.

Here is another simpler example of the same problem: http://jsfiddle.net/88f2L4h1/ . In this case I'm using the solution from https://stackoverflow.com/a/8418039/2482744 to achieve equal height divs.

Comment: Yes, exactly that. ( I couldn't understand the problem. )

Comment: @C-linkNepal go to the jsfiddle, look at the output. At that point, without SVG, it is fine. Click the button. Now it is not fine.

Comment: How can I understand what's not fine, what exactly you want...?

Comment: @C-linkNepal When clicking the button, the black should all turn into red, without any layout changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can explicitly set your SVG element's width and height to the same values as its parent container using `clientWidth` and `clientHeight`.

Here's a fiddle demonstrating it using D3.

http://jsfiddle.net/ofuh701p/8/

Comment: That's my jsfiddle. Click Update in the top left and send me the new link (the /4/ should change to /7/ or something).

Comment: Sorry, fixed link to fiddle.

Comment: Thanks. I basically did this in the end (see below) although I don't understand why it has to be done this way. Also I don't get why yours is able to handle keeping the style as `table-cell`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the kind of thing I want:

http://jsfiddle.net/ofuh701p/6/

I was hoping that this could be solved using just CSS, as this seems like a really simple requirement and I can't understand why the SVG messes things up so much. This solution uses uses javascript to set the height dynamically based on the DOM elements which feels like a hack:

```
var c = Raphael("braces-canvas", 50, $("#selectable-container").outerHeight());
```

Also the `div`s are now using `display: inline-block`.